# Android - Why is Whatsapp not seen as a user installed application?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I'm trying to distinguish between system applications and applications installed by user
with the following piece of code:

```
public void getInstalledApps() {
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> applications = pm.getInstalledApplications(flags);

    for(ApplicationInfo appInfo : applications) {
        if((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            // System application
            Log.i("TESTAPPSYSTEM", pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString());
        } else {
            // Installed by user
            Log.i("TESTAPPUSER",  pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But in Android Studio's console i saw that:

```
06-17 15:19:42.639  14822-14822/it.example.myapplication.app I/TESTAPPSYSTEM WhatsApp
```

On the contrary of others applications installed by user (like Telegram), Whatsapp is seen as a system application, not as one installed by user: why?

Comment: Was WhatsApp pre-installed on your device?

Comment: Now I get it: Whatsapp was included in the last ROM I installed.
I checked the ROM's features and Whatsapp was in there.
But how can I tell between installed or included apps if they are included in the ROM?

Comment: What do you mean? By definition, an app that is included in the ROM is a system app

Comment: I want to be able to close the running installed apps (not the running system ones), and in order to do this I need to see Whatsapp as a user installed app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp is pre-installed either with your Android operating system from the manufacturer or by a ROM you have applied to your phone, you can not change this, however if you have a rooted phone then you can uninstall WhatsApp then install it from the play store so that it is installed as a user application not a system application. Furthermore there are apps out there which close system apps, although once again you would need to have root access to perform this task I believe.